# Using PCDLoader from three.js in APS Viewer (with v 71 three.js)

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've tried to load a .pcd file format with PCDLoader from three.js. The default method doesn't seem to work. I guess this is a version difference issue.

I've included scripts in the HTML:

```
 <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.2/build/three.module.js",
        "PCDLoader": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.2/examples/jsm/loaders/PCDLoader.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
```

and on the extension I called

```
const loader = new PCDLoader();
loader.load(
    function (points) {

        const pointsobject = new window.THREE.PointCloud(points.geometry, points.material);

        viewer.overlays.addScene('pointclouds');
        viewer.overlays.addMesh(pointsobject, 'pointclouds');
    }
);
```

Altought loading process is 100% and without error, when I add the points object to the scene of viewer `viewer.overlays.addMesh(pointsobject, 'pointclouds')` it gives this error:

```
WebGLRenderer Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

I've tried Potree integration to APS viewer too and it works but if I need to translate every file to Potree format before usage and put all the files to local folder then it doesn't look like a optimal option to me.

Is there a way to use PCDLoader in APS?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is most likely a compatibility issue. The APS Viewer uses three.js r71, and you're using a point cloud loader for three.js r152. I would suggest to check if the `PCDLoader` class is available for the older three.js versions, and if not, you could try backporting it. The Potree loader you found was actually backported to three.js r71 as well: https://github.com/petrbroz/potree-core/tree/experiment/three71.